# Running cmd as Administrator with elevated rights using Java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have elevated rights on my system i.e, I can right click on cmd.exe and run it as Administrator.
But when I do the same thing using Java, I am not able to do that. It asks my for Administrator password which I don't have.

I am using following command:

```
runas /profile /user:Administrator /savecred cmd /c start PATH\\to\\my\\file.bat
```

Comment: Create a shortcut of the file. Right-click -> Properties. Shortcut tab -> Advanced. Check 'Run as administrator'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the password of the Administrator, you can use this:

```
public static void changeUserPassword(String username, String password) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net user "+username+" "+password);
        //This runs without needing Administrative Rights...
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

But you can't run a jar file as Administrator, unless you are in the Administrator account.  Now, if you want a program you created to run as Administrator than I recommend you downloading **Launch4j**, this will turn your jar file into an exe file which will allow you to run it as Administrator...

**Launch4j** Download Link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/

Other than those ways that I listed, there is no way (*yet*) to auto-launch a file as Administrator...